# How to insert node Date() into postgresql timestamp column?

Tags: node.js, postgresql, date, timestamp, momentjs

I want to update several records with the same time, and I can't figure out how to do it.

I've tried various combos with pg-promise and moment and node alone:

```
myTs = Date();
myTs = moment(new Date()).format("YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss");
```

with sql:

```
UPDATE mytable set ts = $1;
UPDATE mytable set ts = $1::timestamp;
```

errors:

```
 time zone "gmt-0800" not recognized
```

Comment: Your error message is claiming that the column has a mismatched type: `BIGINT` instead of `TIMESTAMP`. Is that correct? If it is, you'll need to store your date in a numeric format and not as an ISO date string.

Comment: Use `timestamptz` as the database column type, and insert JavaScript type `Date` directly. It just will work, and correctly.

Answer (score 1):

It is better to store timestamps in a database in UTC format without time zones.

Suppose there is a table (PostgreSQL):

```
create table test_time (utc_time timestamp);
```

To insert the current UTC timestamp:

```
const res = await db.query({
  text: "insert into test_time (utc_time) values ($1) returning *",
  values: [new Date(new Date().toISOString())],
});
```

Or you can insert the current `Date` with a time zone depending on your runtime:

```
const res = await db.query({
  text: "insert into test (date) values ($1) returning *",
  values: [new Date()],
});
```